# Am I using copy ctors/move ctors/shared_ptr correctly?

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

Here is my simple example: there is a class A with few primitive members and a class B with few primitive members but also a collection of objects of type A.

This is my A class:

```
#pragma once

#include<string>

class Hero
{
private:
    long id;
    std::string name;
    int level;
    static long currentId;
public:
    Hero();
    Hero(std::string name, int level);
    Hero(const Hero &hero);
    Hero(Hero &&hero);
    Hero& operator=(const Hero &hero);
    Hero& Hero::operator=(const Hero &&hero);
    long GetId() const { return this->id; }
    std::string GetName() const { return this->name; }
    int GetLevel() const { return this->level; }
    void SetName(const std::string &name);
    void SetLevel(const int &level);
};

#include"Hero.h"

long Hero::currentId = 0;

Hero::Hero(std::string name, int level):name(name), level(level), id(++currentId) 
{

}

Hero::Hero():name(""), level(0), id(++currentId)
{

}

Hero::Hero(const Hero &hero):id(hero.id), name(hero.name), level(hero.level)
{

}

Hero::Hero(Hero &&hero):id(hero.id), name(hero.name), level(hero.level)
{

}

Hero& Hero::operator=(const Hero &hero)
{
    this->id = hero.id;
    this->name = hero.name;
    this->level = hero.level;
    return *this;
}

Hero& Hero::operator=(const Hero &&hero)
{
    this->id = hero.id;
    this->name = hero.name;
    this->level = hero.level;
    return *this;
}

void Hero::SetName(const std::string &name) 
{
    this->name = name; 
}

void Hero::SetLevel(const int &level) 
{
    this->level = level; 
}
```

This is my B class:

```
#pragma once

#include"Hero.h"
#include<vector>
#include<memory>

class Race
{
private:
    static long currentId;
    long id;
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>> heroes;
    Race(const Race &race); //disable copy constructor
    Race& operator =(const Race &race); //disable assign operator
public:
    Race();
    explicit Race(std::string name);
    std::string GetName() const { return this->name; }
    void SetName(std::string name);
    void AddHero(Hero &&hero);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>> GetHeroes() const { return heroes; }
};

   #include "Race.h"

long Race::currentId = 0;

Race::Race(std::string name):name(name), heroes(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>>()), id(++currentId)
{

}

Race::Race():name(""), heroes(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>>()), id(++currentId)
{

}

void Race::SetName(std::string name)
{
    this->name=name;
}

void Race::AddHero(Hero &&hero)
{
    heroes.push_back(std::make_shared<Hero>(hero));
}
```

And this is my main:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include"Race.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Hero elvesHero1("Demon hunter", 8);
    Hero elvesHero2("Warden", 4);
    Race nightElf("Night elf");
    nightElf.AddHero(std::move(elvesHero1));
    nightElf.AddHero(std::move(elvesHero2));
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Hero>> heroes=nightElf.GetHeroes();
    return 0;
}
```

One remark: When the debugger hits `nightElf.AddHero(std::move(elvesHero1));` it enters Hero's copy constructor. Shouldn't it go through move constructor?

I just want start on the right foot, so I am waiting for your tips.

LE: If I modify the `AddHero` method like this:

```
void Race::AddHero(Hero &&hero)
{
    heroes.push_back(std::make_shared<Hero>(std::move(hero)));
}
```

it gives the parameter `std:move(hero)` instead of hero.  It enters move constructor instead of copy constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, in your header file, you don't need the `Hero::` qualification on your move assignment operator. Secondly, you are defining it as `Hero& Hero::operator=(const Hero &&hero);`. Think about what this is saying - it's saying if you have an rvalue reference to a `Hero` object, then:

1. You cannot modify it because it is `const`
2. You want to utilize move semantics (specifically, `std::move`) which will modify the original object and leave it with an empty value.

Hence, your move constructor should *always* be of the form `Hero& Hero::operator=(Hero&& hero)`. The implementation should also be using `std::move`:

```
Hero& operator=(Hero&& hero)
    : id(std::move(hero.id),
      name(std::move(hero.name),
      level(std::move(hero.level)
{ }
```

For your `AddHero` methods, a `Hero&& hero` might be an rvalue reference, but without the `std::move` for its elements, you're basically saying "take an rvalue reference to Hero, and call copy constructors on each of its elements when you utilize `make_shared<Hero>`".

Note that moving vs copying for basic types like `int` or `long` won't have any performance difference.

That being said, you're doing a **lot of work here for no benefit**. The rule is, unless you have written a custom destructor, you don't need to write custom copy constructors, copy assignment operators or move assignment operators - the compiler will generate defaults which are correct. It is only when you are managing memory (hence have a `delete` or `delete[]` in a destructor somewhere) that you need to implement these.

Finally, a few other small points. Your constructors should be taking strings by `const &`, ie, `explicit Race(const std::string& name)`. Usage of `this->` to return member variables is a bit unidiomatic in C++, likewise in copy constructors and the like, instead of `this->id = hero.id;` it's more idiomatic to simply write `id = hero.id;`.

I'd suggest reading the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) post on stackoverflow to get a better understanding of copy construction and copy assignment.

Comment: As we are in C++11 land, I would strongly recommend moving from Rule of Three to [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html). Also, it would be nice to mention the [Quasi Classes](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf) paper. But +1 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Yuushi

I just want to emphasis this bit:

```
Hero elvesHero1("Demon hunter", 8);

nightElf.AddHero(std::move(elvesHero1));
```

Here `elvesHero1` is an object. When you call `AddHero()` you create a new object that is shared. So you now have **two** independent "Demon hunter" objects (the first is automatic`elvesHero1` the other is dynamic and controlled by a shared pointer inside `nightElf`.

Is this really what you wanted?

I assume that you want to create `Hero`(s) dynamically. Thus usually they are going to be created with `new` and controlled by a smart pointer. Thus the interface to `Race` should reflect this and accept the appropriate smart pointer in its interface `AddHero()`.

Thus I would expect to see:

```
 class Race
 {
      void AddHero(std::shared_ptr<Hero>& hero);
 };
 int main()
 {
     // STUF
     std::shared_ptr<Hero> = new elvesHero1("Demon hunter", 8);

     Race nightElf("Night elf");
     nightElf.AddHero(std::move(elvesHero1));
 }
```

The next question you want to ask `is std::shared_ptr the correct smart pointer`. I can't answer this as I don't know enough about the app. Do you expect multiple ownership of he object? Or is `Race` going to have exclusive ownership and share references externally?